# In Spring JDBC, how to set RESULT SET HOLDABILITY on statements?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I would like to prepare statements with `resultSetHoldability` parameter set to `ResultSet.CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT`:

```
PreparedStatement stmnt = conn.prepareStatement(sql, resultSetType, resultSetConcurrency,
    ResultSet.CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT)
```

...and the same for prepareCall. I am currently using Spring's `JdbcTemplate` and `SimpleJdbcCall`, because it has that convenient `declareParameters()` and `execute(Map paramValues)` methods.

So what would be the simplest way to set `resultSetHoldability`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use one of the various `query` methods on `JdbcTemplate` which take a `PreparedStatementCreator` object as their first argument.

You give it a `PreparedStatementCreator` object which constructs the `PreparedStatement` from the supplied `Connection`, and returns that, e.g.

```
PrepatedStatementCreator psc = new PrepatedStatementCreator() {
   public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection conn) {
      return conn.prepareStatement(sql, resultSetType, resultSetConcurrency, 
          resultSetHoldability);
   }
}

jdbcTemplate.query(psc, ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following method.

```
   execute(ConnectionCallback action)
```

The connectioncallback gives you access to the connection object, which has a `setHoldability` method

Comment: Did I understand correctly, that I should invoke execute() with my own connection callback before calling any other query() or call() methods? And it will use the connection with proper settings then?

Comment: nope - you use the connectionCallback to do any jdbc actions that you want to do. This is because you are not guaranteed to get the same connection when you call execute as when you call query.

Comment: So I get hold of Connections, set it up and then... manually do all the stuff that Spring would normally do for me?